# Как подключить БД к WPF-приложению на .NET 6, если нет файла App.config?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Делаю WPF-прилодежение на .NET 6.0 и хочу подключить БД (SQLite). Однако, во всех туториалах (metanit.com, например) для этого используется файл App.config, который есть только в приложениях на .NET Framework. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: App.config можно и в .NET Core добавить. Просто вручную его создаёшь и выставляешь копирование в выходную папку. Подключаешь либу "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" (из .NET Framework) и спокойно читаешь. Но App.config устаревший формат. Сейчас модно в json хранить (в ASP .NET Core, например, appsettings.json используется). НО для SQlite не обязательно конфиг иметь. Такая БД (встраиваемая СУБД) обычно применяется для внутренних нужд приложения и путь там зачастую захардкожен (или в папке с приложением, или в каком-нибудь AppData). Так что конфигурировать там обычно нечего.

Comment: Если очень хочется, то без проблем можно и json использовать. Создаёшь файл appsettings.json (имя тут не важно), выставляешь у него "Copy to Output Directory"="Copy if newer", подключаешь либы "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" и "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" и считываешь: создаёшь ConfigurationBuilder, потом AddJsonFile, потом Build и из результата (интерфейс IConfigurationRoot) спокойно считываешь, например так: var str = conf["ConnectionString"].